# Setting trigonometric polynomial terms to zero

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider an expansion

$$\eta = a\cos (kx-\omega t) +\frac{1}{2} a^2 k \cos 2 (kx-\omega t).$$

I would like to compute expansions like

$$ V = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int _0^{2\pi} \eta^2  \ d\theta ,$$

with $\theta = kx-\omega t$ and then find all nonzero terms of this. The simplest way for me to do this, instead of integrating the above, is to use `TrigExpand`, and then collect all of the terms and see which terms belong to trigonometric basis 1. However, when I do this for complicated cases, it becomes a burden to do this by eye. I'd like to set all terms that still depend on a trig function to zero.

Here's a sample code that illustrates my problem.

```
\[Eta][x_, t_] := 
1/2 ((I*k/\[Omega]*A)*
  Exp[I*(k*x - \[Omega]*t)] + (1/2*I*(k/\[Omega])^2*k*A^2)*
  Exp[2*I*(k*x - \[Omega]*t)] + (-I*k/\[Omega]*Ap)*
  Exp[-I*(k*x - \[Omega]*t)] + 
 1/2*I*(k/\[Omega])^2*k*Ap^2*Exp[-2*I*(k*x - \[Omega]*t)]);
```

Using

```
TrigExpand[1/2*\[Eta][x, t]^2]
```

I find 
$$-\frac{A^2 \text{Ap}^2 k^6}{16 \omega ^4}-\frac{\text{Ap}^4 e^{-4 i (k x-t \omega )} k^6}{32 \omega ^4}-\frac{A^4 e^{4 i (k x-t \omega )} k^6}{32 \omega ^4}-\frac{A \text{Ap}^2 e^{-i (k x-t \omega )} k^4}{8 \omega ^3}+\frac{A^2 \text{Ap} e^{i (k x-t \omega )} k^4}{8 \omega ^3}+\frac{\text{Ap}^3 e^{-3 i (k x-t \omega )} k^4}{8 \omega ^3}-\frac{A^3 e^{3 i (k x-t \omega )} k^4}{8 \omega ^3}+\frac{A \text{Ap} k^2}{4 \omega ^2}-\frac{\text{Ap}^2 e^{-2 i (k x-t \omega )} k^2}{8 \omega ^2}-\frac{A^2 e^{2 i (k x-t \omega )} k^2}{8 \omega ^2}$$

Out of the 10 terms, only 2 are non-zero. In general I don't want to use an operation like integration, as $a$ will have a weak dependence on (x,t) that is crucial for deriving $\eta$, but can be ignored in the integration. Is there any other way to send these terms to 0?

Comment: Why don't just subtract them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
TrigExpand[1/2*\[Eta][x, t]^2] /. Exp[_]->0
```

which gives

```
-((A^2 Ap^2 k^6)/(16 ω^4)) + (A Ap k^2)/(4 ω^2)
```

Comment: Great, thanks @Bill